# Starting point of teb_local_planner

Tags: ros, navigation, teb-local-planner, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Right now i have a car which I want to control with the teb_local_planner at walking speed.
And as the base_link is above the rear axle, the plan is constructed from there through the footprint and out of the front bumper.

So my question is, as the plan inside the footprint is irrelevant, can I use the front bumper as the starting point for the planner?

[image: local path]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278508/starting-point-of-teb_local_planner/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2018-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even if the plan inside the footprint appears to be irrelevant, it is not.
The car is modeled by a unicycle model, in particular non-holonomic kinematics including a limited turning radius.
Changing the position to the front axle would result in a substantially different model w.r.t. the real kinematics.

For some basic information the car-like model, refer to [LaValle's book](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/ch13.pdf).
You might also check the [teb_local_planner carlike tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner/Tutorials/Planning%20for%20car-like%20robots).

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2018-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Al53](https://answers.ros.org/users/30273/al53/) on 2023-01-21**:
Updated link for Chapter 13 of the [Steven LaValle book](http://lavalle.pl/planning/ch13.pdf)